# Swift: Continuous resizing of tableViewCell while user types in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

## Introduction

**Context:**

I'm creating one of my first apps but I've ran into an issue I cannot figure out.

- I have tableView with cells packed with quite a few UIElements. All constraints are done using the EasyPeasy library which basically just sets auto layout constraints ( I have tried setting them manually also). The UITextView in question is constrained by various numbers to the left, right, top and bottom, I have no constraints on it for height or width.
- in cellForRowAt indexPath: I set the textView delegate for each cells textView to self, using a delegate property declared within the cells custom class. I also tag every textView with its cells indexPath.row (gives `textView.tag` integer in textViewDidChange method).

**Issue/acknowledgments:**

- After browsing SO a lot I've found a few questions alike this but I have not been able to make them work for me, I have implemented parts of them that felt logic to my case. I believe the problem differencing my situation from those questions lies in that for my cell design to work the cells has to have a height of `itemHeight` or higher.
- I have noticed that as I type into the textview the textview itself increases in height (even below the cells border but its not visible as it reaches that point), however the cell itself doesn't resize.
- I've tried with a cell that only contains a textView so the problem must lie in the textViewDidchange or heightForRowAt indexPath methods.

**Question:**

*What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't the cells height change dynamically as I type in the textView?*

## Code:

```
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
       var newframe = textView.frame
       newframe.size.height = textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height + itemHeight[textView.tag]
       textView.frame = newframe
       let ndxPath = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)
       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: ndxPath) as! EventsCell
       cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: cell.frame.width, height: textView.frame.height)

         tableView.beginUpdates()
         tableView.setNeedsLayout() //have tried without this line
         tableView.layoutIfNeeded() //have tried without this line
         tableView.endUpdates()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if UITableViewAutomaticDimension > itemHeight[indexPath.row] {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        } else {
            return itemHeight[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

**TextView constraints:**

```
   let containerView : UIView = {
        let cv = UIView(frame: .zero)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        return cv
    }()

    let eventText : GrowingTextView = {   // GrowingTextView is a extension to a regular UITextView
        let tv = GrowingTextView()
        tv.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
        tv.isScrollEnabled = false
        var delegate: UITextViewDelegate?
        tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 0, 1)
        tv.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
     }()

 override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    containerView.addSubview(eventText)
    contentView.addSubview(containerView)

    containerView .easy.layout([Height(CGFloat(95 * itemCount)), Left(8), Right(8)])
    eventText .easy.layout([Left(77), Right(5), Top(90), Bottom(4)])

 }
```

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: Have you attached the textView bottom to the cell bottom?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri It is autolayouted 4 px from the bottom of a UIView which is autolayouted to have the exact frame as the cell contentView. Concept code: `UIView.addSubview(textView)` then `contentView.addSubview(textView)`. I've added the constraint code for the textView in an edit

Comment: You should have the height calculating constraints laid out in such a way that autolayout will be able to tell the height by looking at your textView. eg: If there is only a textView in your cell. Attach the top and bottom of the textView to the top and bottom of the contentView respectively.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I tried attaching it to the contentView directly but it still doesn't extend the cell ( I assigned contentView.backgroundColor = .red to check but it didn't expand, but the textViews text goes on over the next cell). Perhaps there is something wrong in my textViewDidChange method?

Comment: Have you tried with only the textView?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I tried with only the textView and it does not change the cell height. So it must be the textViewDidChange method or the heightForRowAt indexPath method thats wrong. Would you mind guiding a little further, if I may ask?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177596/discussion-between-rakesha-shastri-and-theoadahl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The constraints that determine the height should be laid out in such a way that the `textView` is attached directly to the top and bottom of the `contentView` or to views which are connected to the top and bottom of the `contentView`, so that autolayout can make out the height by connecting the constraints.
- Make sure that you do not mention a height for the `textView` and **disable scrolling**. Let automatic dimension take care of all that.
- Now all you need to do is call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` on `textViewDidChange`

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/rakeshashastri/resizing-textView-in-tableviewcell) which demonstrates the same.

---

**OP Edit:**

- You should store the additional height that you add in a variable in the cell class so the cells can reload an appropriate height when the tableVIew is reloaded.
- You should also change textViewDidChange method

  ```
  cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: cell.frame.width, height: textView.frame.height)
  ```

  to

  ```
  let newFrame = ”originalCellHeight” - ”originalTextViewHeight” + textView.contentSize.height

  cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: cell.frame.width, height: newFrame )`
  ```

Comment: Marked as answered from text in chat discussion

Comment: Can you edit and add what part helped you get to the answer so that it can help others?