# How to resize a UITextView that automatically resize its width and height based on the content and fixed width when reaches certain value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I had tried to create the autoresize UITextView with the following code.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
     let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
     let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
     textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)

}
```

When i type on the first character, it does not resize the width to the character. The other solution i tried is this.

```
 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
     let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
     let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
     textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

}
```

It width stuck on the first character, only one character per line with this solutions. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731451/swift-continuous-resizing-of-tableview-while-user-types-in-a-uitextview/51735120#51735120

Comment: This is because in the `sizeThatFits` method you are telling it the maximum width it can be is the current width so it just adapts the height.  Are you trying to get it to expand horizontally until some point at which it will then expand vertically?

Comment: using height constraint of Textview you can do this.

Comment: add this line after resize the textview self.view.layoutIfNeeded() .

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth yes , -Rakesha Shastri nope it does not help but thanks, -KKRocks how to use constraint to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    let maximumWidth: CGFloat = 200 // Change as appropriate for your use.
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: maximumWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
```

You will need to come up with a way to determine the maximum width as I have just hardcoded it for now.

This will expand the `UITextView` horizontally until 200 points and then start expanding vertically.