# How to set minimum height for UITextView that grows dynamically?

Tags: swift, io, uitextview

I have a `GrowingTextView` which increases its height when content size increases.

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tvHeight.constant = 200
    tv.sizeToFit()
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.contentSize.height > 200 {
        textView.sizeToFit()
    }  
    updateScroll()
}
```

I want to set minimum height to the text view as 200, but it is not working. I tried in IB as well as code. The UI has the below components each with 16 as leading and trailing and 8 as top and bottom constraints.

```
UITextField - Title
GrowingTextView - tv
UITextField - Author
UITextField
```

[image: screenshot]

How to set the min height for text view?

Comment: This should help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735120/7734643. You might need to set an extra height constraint for the minimum height that you mentioned.

Comment: I have a working dynamic text view. But I am not able to set the min height. The default min height is 33 and it grows as per the content. I want the height to be 200.

Comment: The height constraint should be of type `greaterThanOrEqualTo`

Comment: What is `tvHeight` ?

Comment: It is the height constraint for the text view (`NSLayoutConstraint`).

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio It is not working.

Comment: @jsloop show all of your code, especially the constraints. Also please go through the repo in the linked answer.

Comment: I am setting this using constraints. I have added the screenshot. Nothing much in the code.

Comment: is `GrowingTextView` a custom view?

Comment: Yes. I have set the class of `UITextView` to `GrowinTextView` which is a library: https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the library that you mentioned `GrowingTextView` in your comment you can use the parameter `minHeight = 200`.

```
tv.minHeight = 200
```

In that case I think you don't need the height constant `tvHeight.constant = 200`. Here is an example:

```
override viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   tv.minHeight = 200
   tv.sizeToFit()
}
```